# Every time I boot into my computer my internet runs at full speed (50Mb/s) after about 10 minutes it drops to (6Mb/s)

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager, wicd

The only way I can fix it is to change to wicd, then it does it again, so I'll change back and forth between wicd and network-manager. 
any ideas on what's causing this? 
I have a full duplex rtl8169, I had this problem before I tried installing the proprietary drivers.
 I also used

```
sudo ethtool -s eth2 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on
```

to make sure everything was setup at its maximum potential. I am still having this issue, and I never had this problem with windows.

Comment: Does this also happen on your local LAN?  How long ago did you try this on Window$?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be happening on my local lan, and i've been on ubuntu for weeks and it has been doing it, and all the other windows computers in the house are working at max speed

Comment: Weird... Can you turn off `autoneg`?

Comment: Now I did, should I reboot afterwards?

Comment: No, a `sudo service networking restart` should be enough...

Comment: okay so I disabled it, and restarted after about 30 minutes it started doing it again

Comment: What did you do to test the intra-LAN speed?

Comment: Okay so I get this whenever I try sudo service networking restart
stop: Job failed while stopping
start: Job is already running: networking

Comment: Reboot then... What did you do to test the Intra-LAN speed?

Comment: I actually did not do a lan test. I thought I did, but after looking I realized that I didn't. But so far it seems that a ifconfig eth0 down followed by ifconfig eth0 up seems to have worked for me to reboot the network. and I seem to be having a steady internet connection now, My last question is how to I turn the autoneg off at boot?

Answer (score 1):

Go to a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>and type:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

in your eth2 section add:

```
iface eth2 inet ...
    ...
    ...
    up sleep 5; ethtool -s eth2 -s eth2 speed 100 duplex full
```

(note the 100, not 1000: internally on the LAN, 100 is slow but towards the Internet 100 is fast)  If that works reliably for some time (a week), upgrade it to 1000!

Comment: I used a different method before I saw this, and it seems to be working for the time being, if I have more trouble I will try this one.

Comment: So I ultimately just gave up. I grabbed a half duplex 10/100 card from work and called it a day. Thank you for all the help, I can't thank you enough, I love this community

Comment: accepting my answer and upvoting is better then a thank you as my reputation will go up!  ;-)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote right now, sadly

Answer (score 1):

So after messing around I figured out how to fix my issue,

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

I entered

```
ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100 duplex full
```

above the `exit 0` and this seemed to fix it at least for now.